# How can I combine point estimates and standard errors from non-independent datasets?

Tags: bootstrap, resampling, case-control-study

I will conduct a 1:2 or 1:3 matched case-control study in order to examine risk factors related to a rare disease.
Under this study, I'm planning to repeat selection of matched controls for at least 100 times because there are many possible controls.
And each time we select controls, I will apply the data to a model to get parameter estimates.
Then, I'd like to combine the point estimates and standard errors from the 100 or more resampling data.

Are there any ideas to get the combined estimate?

Although I don't know whether these are right or wrong, I have the following ideas:

1. Rubin's method:
   As like multiple imputation strategy, consider the resampling datasets as multiply imputed datasets, and then combine inferences from different datasets.
   https://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/statug/63033/HTML/default/viewer.htm#statug_mianalyze_sect012.htm
   Are there any problems related to this method?
2. Bootstrap method:
   Consider the resampling datasets as bootstrapped datasets, and then simply calculate mean and standard deviation of the point estimates.
   I think it would be a problem as random sampling is not done.
3. Meta-analytic method:
   Interpret the resampling datasets as independent trials' datasets, and then use the traditional meta-anaystic methods for analysis.
   I think it would also be a problem because resampling datasets are not independent.
4. Increase numbers of matched controls:
   Give up the resampling, but increase the numbers of matched controls.
   One of the problems with this way would be that there are some cases that can't meet the requirements "1:n" when n is increased.

Please let me know, if there are any suggestions or if you have any solution for this topic.

Comment: is there a reason the n in 1:n needs to be the same for matched groups?

Comment: are you aware of this work -- http://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/10.1111/1467-9876.00242/abstract , http://www5.statcan.gc.ca/olc-cel/olc.action?objId=12-001-X20060029546&objType=47&lang=en&limit=0 ? I believe you don't have to fret with matching 1:1, as combining the estimates is just too methodologically tricky. They are not independent, to begin with, since they will have the same controls every time. And this lack of independence is very difficult to trace and meaningfully incorporate into any estimates/variances aggregation strategy.